# activeDot in recharts changes when resizing chart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

In my React Webapp I want to display a chart using recharts. I want the user to be able to select a datapoint, so
I changed the Tooltip trigger to "click". This works fine so far, but my problem is that when the size of the chart
changes, the active datapoint and the cursor will change and not be the one the user selected to begin with.
I think the change is due to the fact that the position of the active datapoint does not change even though
it should because of the resize event.
I use react-grid-layout to have my charts in a flexible grid. I tested my chart without react-grid-layout and the active data point will still change.

How can I keep my originally selected datapoint as active dot?

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
  <LineChart
    data={props.data}
    margin={{
      top: 5,
      right: 30,
      left: 20,
      bottom: 5,
    }}
  >
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <XAxis dataKey="Time" />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip
      trigger="click"
    />
    <Legend />
      <Line
        dataKey="value"
        stroke="#5c58b0"
      />
  </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```